# Hyperref package - Appendices are connected to chapters

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, appendix

I am using the hyperref package. The chapters are properly linked but the appendices are connected to chapters and I am not able to find out the issue. I would appreciate it if you can help me with this.

```
\documentclass[ece,dissertation]{puthesis}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,bbm,bm,graphicx,multirow,pifont,upgreek,verbatim,braket} 
\usepackage[absolute]{textpos}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\newcommand\fix[1]{\textcolor{red}{#1}}
\usepackage{braket} 
\usepackage{mathtools}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Tr}{Tr}
\newcommand{\cmark}{\ding{51}}%
\newcommand{\xmark}{\ding{55}}%
\DeclareMathOperator{\sF}{\mathcal{F}}
\DeclareMathOperator{\sZ}{\mathcal{Z}}
\DeclareMathOperator{\sP}{\mathcal{P}}
\DeclareMathOperator{\bx}{\mathbf{x}}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmin}{argmin}
\DeclareMathOperator{\R}{Re}
\DeclareMathOperator{\I}{Im}

\newcommand{\imag}{\mathrm{i}}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,braket,upgreek,bm,verbatim}
\usepackage{graphicx,tabularx,xcolor} 
%\usepackage[colorlinks=true,bookmarks=false,citecolor=blue,urlcolor=blue]{hyperref} %
\definecolor{darkblue}{rgb}{0,0,0.5}

%\usepackage{xcolor}
\newcommand{\etal}{\textit{et al}.}
\usepackage[absolute]{textpos}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{multirow}
%\newcommand\fix[1]{\textcolor{red}{#1}}
\newcommand\bl[1]{\textcolor{blue}{#1}}
\pdfsuppresswarningpagegroup=1 %

\def\bx{\mathbf{x}}
\def\by{\mathbf{y}}
\def\bz{\mathbf{z}}
\def\bbD{{\bm{\mathcal{D}}}}
\def\cN{\mathcal{N}}
\def\cF{\mathcal{F}}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,bbm,bm}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{braket}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{relsize}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage{accents}
\newcommand{\dbtilde}[1]{\accentset{\approx}{#1}}
\newcommand{\vardbtilde}[1]{\tilde{\raisebox{0pt}[0.85\height]{$\tilde{#1}$}}}

\makeatletter
\ams@newcommand{\iiiiint}{\DOTSI\protect\MultiIntegral{5}}
\renewcommand{\MultiIntegral}[1]{%
  \edef\ints@c{\noexpand\intop
    \ifnum#1=\z@\noexpand\intdots@\else\noexpand\intkern@\fi
    \ifnum#1>\tw@\noexpand\intop\noexpand\intkern@\fi
    \ifnum#1>\thr@@\noexpand\intop\noexpand\intkern@\fi
    \ifnum#1>4 \noexpand\intop\noexpand\intkern@\fi % <---- added
    \noexpand\intop
    \noexpand\ilimits@
  }%
  \futurelet\@let@token\ints@a
}
\makeatother


\pdfsuppresswarningpagegroup=1 %
\def\bx{\mathbf{x}}
\def\bz{\mathbf{z}}
\def\bbD{{\bm{\mathcal{D}}}}
\def\cN{\mathcal{N}}

\usepackage{stackengine}
\newcommand{\op}[1]{\mathop{}\!\ensurestackMath{\stackon[-.95ex]{%
  \mathbf{#1}}{\smash{\mathbf{\hat{}}}}}}
\newcommand{\opdag}[1]{\mathop{}\!\op{#1}^{\dag}}

\newcommand{\appropto}{\mathrel{\vcenter{
  \offinterlineskip\halign{\hfil$##$\cr
    \propto\cr\noalign{\kern2pt}\sim\cr\noalign{\kern-2pt}}}}}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
colorlinks=true,
linkcolor=black,
filecolor=blue,
citecolor=darkblue,  
urlcolor=black,
}

% Title of thesis (used on cover and in abstract).
\title{Toward Quantum Networking with Frequency-bin Qudits on Integrated Platforms}

\author{Karthik Myilswamy}{Myilswamy, Karthik}

% First is long title of degree (used on cover).
% Second is abbreviation for degree (used in abstract).
% Third is the month the degree was (will be) awarded (used on cover
% and abstract).
% Last is the year the degree was (wlll be) awarded (used on cover
% and abstract).
\pudegree{Doctor of Philosophy}{Ph.D.}{October}{2023}

% Major professor (used in abstract).
% Use \majorprofs{...} if you have more than one professor.
\majorprof{Andrew M. Weiner}

% Campus (used only on cover)
\campus{West Lafayette}

\input{mydefs}
\newcommand{\margins}{\Repeat{Show where the margins for the page are.}{4}}
\let\en=\ensuremath
\newcommand{\ve}[2]{\en{#1_1},~\en{#1_2},\ \ldots,~\en{#1_{#2}}}




\begin{document}

\volume

% Front matter (dedication, etc.).
\include{front}

\include{CH1-Introduction/main}
\include{CH2-SpectralCompression/main}
\include{CH3-TemporalModulation/main}
\include{CH4-BayesianTomography/main}
\include{CH5-VernierModulation/main}
\include{CH6-FutureWorks/main}

\bibliography{References1}

%\appendices
\begin{appendices}
\include{App-BFC_SpectralCompression}

\include{App-BayesianInference}
\include{App-CrossCorrelation}
% A vita is optional for masters theses
% and required for doctoral dissertations.
\include{Publication}
\end{appendices}
\include{VITA}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx,  Not related to your problem, but several packages are loaded more than once -- `amsmath` at least three times by itself and once by `mathtools`,  Do clean those up.  Also, we don't know what's in  your `\include`d files, so giving a knowledgeable answer will be difficult.

Comment: nobody can test your code. But try \usepackage[hypertexnames=false]{hyperref}

Comment: You have `\begin{appendices}`, but i don't see the appendix package.  Is that included in your document class?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer  \usepackage[hypertexnames=false]{hyperref}  fixed it. Thank you